# How to configure EF Code First to not map a specific type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I was getting the following error when runing such this code:

```
var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
var list = dbContext.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
```

From the changes I made recently to codes I understood that because I added an event to the base class it causes all the problems:

```
public PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChangedEvent { get; set; }
```

Applying the NotMapped attribute to the above property my codes now are working again.

Now I want to know if there is anyway to autmatically tell EntityFramework to not Map properties of a specific type(which is not my own type, I could not apply any attribute to a .Net's type).

Exception:

```
Sequence does not contains any element.

at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.StructuralTypeMappingGenerator.GetEntityTypeMappingInHierarchy(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EdmEntityType entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.AssociationTypeMappingGenerator.GenerateIndependentAssociationType(EdmAssociationType associationType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.AssociationTypeMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmAssociationType associationType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateAssociationTypes(EdmModel model, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.GenerateDatabaseMapping(EdmModel model, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
```

Comment: I know this is quite old already, but do you know how to determine the property that is causing this exception?  I'm trying to use Code First from a large, existing data layer and I'm seeing this message but I don't know what is causing the problem.

Comment: I did find the culprit by looking at my recent changes I made to code. This is an exception which is EF's bug and not an intentional exception. So I don't know in which circumstances a similar exception may arise.

Comment: Thanks.  So far I'm going through a painful process of starting at the bottom of my entity structure and commenting out code one line at a time to find what works and what fails.  Sometimes the messages are helpful and sometimes I get an exception like this one.

Comment: If you see the exactly the same exception(the inner most method after First is GetEntityTypeMappingInHierarchy), then you have to find entityType in which EF is trying to map. So, I suggest to use the DbModelBuilder.Ignore method to ignore one type at a time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `Ignore` method of `DbModelBuilder` to exclude a type from being mapped.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<PropertyChangedEventHandler>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the fluent interface.

```
public class Context : DbContext
{       
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<TYPE>().Ignore(c => c.PROPERTY);
  }
}
```

Where TYPE and PROPERTY are relevant to your code, or use the Ignore method on the modelBuilder directly to ignore a type completely